# Wordpress menu using hash tags for single page but not when I load blog template

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am creating a single page wordpress site. The primary menu that is in header.php uses hash links to reference content in the page. All the content in the body of the webpage loads into page-home.php. One of the items in my primary menu however is Blog. Blog loads entirely different templates. Once you are in blog, the other menu items do not work because the hash links no longer have the content in the index.php templates to connect to. Should I conditionally load a separate menu for when the url is /blog/? Call a separate header on index.php?

Answer (score 0):

No need for two header.php files.  Inside your current header.php use this code

```
<?php
     if(is_page('Home'){ //or whatever your home page is called
       wp_nav_menu ( $arrayName = array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => 'nav', 'container_class' =>  'navbar-collapse collapse', 'menu_class'    =>  'nav navbar-nav navbar-right' ) );
     } else{
        //INSERT CODE FOR BLOG MENU
       }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! So I would wrap this: 

<?php 
       wp_nav_menu ( $arrayName = array(

        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
        'container'   =>    'nav',
        'container_class'  => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
        'menu_class'   =>  'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

        ) );

      ?>

Comment: Yeah! I've added it to the answer above.

Comment: If wordpress theme only supports one menu, how do I load a separate menu in Else? What I mean is I created a second menu in the wordpress admin. Both my "main menu" and my "second menu" have to be connected to primary. Therefore the "theme_location" => "primary" is the same for both the if and the else.

Comment: Use the code in this link and add it to your functions.php.  You will then be allowed to use the new menu location on the menus page.  Then in your header.php, specify the new menu- location.
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/

Comment: I successfully registered additional menus. Thanks for that link. However something isn't working with my conditionals. I am not sure wordpress can see 'Home' as the home page. My home page is generated by bringing in all my template parts into a page-home.php. However, there is no "Home" in the url when you are on the homepage.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Thanks for all your help.